# How to Compare Selected Query Result in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've challenge to compare 2 tables `agent_comm_summ_mh_new` and `agent_comm_summ_mh_old`, new one will have updated the values.

**This is query 1:**

```
agent_name | participantid | old_net_payment | new_net_payment | sectionorder
leong      | 10116         | 16729.3         | 17285.96        | 10
pwee       | 10260         | 23128.69        | 23287.48        | 10
```

```
select xc.agentname, xc.participantid, bk.value as old_net_payment, xc.value as new_net_payment, xc.sectionorder
from agent_comm_summ_mh_new xc 
inner join agent_comm_summ_mh_old bk on xc.participantid = bk.participantid and xc.buname = bk.buname 
where xc.periodname = 'December 2019' and bk.value<>xc.value and xc.sectionorder=10 and bk.sectionorder=10;
```

and this is query 2

```
agent_name | participantid | pi | subsectionoder
leong      | 10116         | 556.66 | 15
pwee       | 10260         | 158.79 | 15
```

```
select t.participantid, t.subsectionorder, t.agentname, t.value 
from agent_comm_summ_mh_new t 
where t.periodname = 'December 2019' and t.subsectionorder=15;
```

How to write query for both table into 1, I want the result like below:

```
agent_name | participantid | old_net_payment | new_net_payment | sectionorder | pi | subsectionorder
leong      | 10116         | 16729.3         | 17285.96        | 10           | 556.66 | 15
pwee       | 10260         | 23128.69        | 23287.48        | 10           | 158.79 | 15
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the second query limit the results to a particular `subsectionorder`, but not to any specific `sectionorder`? (Or does one `subsectionorder` maybe relate to just one `sectionorder`? If so, does `subsectionorder` 15 belong to `sectionorder` 10?)

Comment: What are the tables' unique keys? Is it `agent_name`? Or `participantid`? Or the two combined? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

You can use self join on the table: `AGENT_COMM_SUMM_MH_NEW` as following:

```
SELECT
    XC.AGENTNAME,
    XC.PARTICIPANTID,
    BK.VALUE   AS OLD_NET_PAYMENT,
    XC.VALUE   AS NEW_NET_PAYMENT,
    XC.SECTIONORDER,
    T.SUBSECTIONORDER, -- ADDED THIS
    T.VALUE    AS PI -- ADDED THIS
FROM
    AGENT_COMM_SUMM_MH_NEW XC
    INNER JOIN AGENT_COMM_SUMM_MH_OLD BK ON XC.PARTICIPANTID = BK.PARTICIPANTID
                                            AND XC.BUNAME = BK.BUNAME
    -- SELF JOIN
    INNER JOIN AGENT_COMM_SUMM_MH_NEW T ON XC.PARTICIPANTID = T.PARTICIPANTID 
WHERE
    XC.PERIODNAME = 'December 2019'
    AND BK.VALUE <> XC.VALUE
    AND XC.SECTIONORDER = 10
    AND BK.SECTIONORDER = 10
    AND T.PERIODNAME = 'December 2019' -- ADDED THIS
    AND T.SUBSECTIONORDER = 15; -- ADDED THIS;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for help, it's works. But, the query result is 322 rows, it should be 323 rows.

Comment: Then do left outer join and put all conditions of T in the ON clause

Comment: @pDimas: We cannot know why you expect one more row than you get. How many rows does your first query return? How many the second? You can also edit your request to show sample data for what's missing. Generally, you'll get better help, if you answer the questions asked in the comments section of your request.